# Can't visit server on some port from other machine in the same intranet

Tags: ubuntu, networking

The Service is working on the server.
The server starts a service on port 9001. It's working on the localhost. Service can be visited through the browser.

The firewall is disabled.

```
$sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

$ service iptables status
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
```

The network is working.
Other machine can get `ping` result. But `telnet` would fail with`connection refused`. And other machince also disabled their firewall.

The server it's using unbuntu 18.04 x86_64.
What could be done to fix this situation?

Comment: Is it even listening on the "public" IP? Or only localhost?

Comment: @HBruijn `$ sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :9001`
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8276/grunt` I think it's listening the public IP? @Lenniey

Comment: The service is only listening on the loopback address 127.0.0.1:9001 as @Lenniey had already guessed. It needs be configured to listen on either *every* ip-address (visible as `0.0.0.0:9001` or IPv6 style `:::9001`) or a specific ip-address