# Can't visit service other than server machine, a seperated backend and frontend project

Tags: nginx

I have asked [a related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/962574/cant-visit-server-on-some-port-from-other-machine-in-the-same-intranet) but has solved it already.
Using `nginx` provided a reverse proxy.
The config file is taking from [project document](https://github.com/docdoku/docdoku-web-front/wiki/Proxy-example-configuration), I paste it below.

Current situation is:
The backend service is working on port 8080. And the front end is working on port 9001.

```
$ netstat -anp |grep 8080
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      26707/java

$ netstat -anp |grep 9001
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      12130/grunt
```

I can visit the localhost:9001 on machine A where the service is running.
While visits from any other machine in the same LAN. It shows the error page. If go with `Inspect`, there is a message in the error page.

```
Cannot open document for: /eplmp-server-rest/api/auth/providers from http://192.168.1.164:8989/
```

`192.168.1.164` is the machine A's IP address.
`/eplmp-server-rest/api/*` should be the endpoint serve by the backend service.

The `XHR` `Network` `Headers` from machine A.

```
General
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/eplmp-server-rest/api/auth/providers
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Requst Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:9001
Referer: http://localhost:9001/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
```

from another machine in the same LAN

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/eplmp-server-rest/api/auth/providers
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01
Origin: http://192.168.1.164:8989
Referer: http://192.168.1.164:8989/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36
```

The related nginx config file.

```
# Simple http proxy
server {
    listen 8989;
    server_name localhost;  

    # Static grunt server
    location / {
        # Use grunt server (require grunt serve command)
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:9001;

        # OR serve static files directly :
        # charset utf-8;
        # root /path/to/docdoku-web-front/dist;
        # expires 0d;
        # access_log off;
    }

    # Webservices REST
    location /api {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
    }    

    # Websocket application
    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/ws;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";  
        proxy_read_timeout 7200s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a separated back-end and front-end project, and can be visit success locally.
So the back-end is correctly config.
The failed request

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/eplmp-server-rest/api/auth/providers
```

So it's not looking into the right domain. Since the machine A's IP is 192.168.1.164, so the right request URL domain should be there.
It's where the front-end should request, and it's not related with the nginx config file.
Finally, find out there is a config file for the front-end, there's a part config the server domain, which was `localhost`. After change it to 192.168.1.164 it worked.
No matter what it is, any separated front-end and back-end project should have somewhere for front-end to connect the back-end.

My wonder was since the front-end was deployed on the same server of the back-end, the `localhost` should work. After I inspect some website, find most of them use a public domain name, like `somewebsite.com` rather than `localhost`, though they may not deployed on the same server, this inspired me. Guess there should some kind of `front-end client`, maybe from the `source` of the `inspect` , which need to connect the real back-end.

Really lack of the front-end knowledge, correction is welcome if there are any mistake.